# Deploying WSO2 APIs in cloud?

Tags: wso2, cloud, wso2-api-manager, wso2-cloud

I have developed few APIs in WSO2 Api Manager locally. Now how do I get the APIs to cloud so that others can access them.

Such as in Mulesoft Anypoint STudio for APIs has an iPAAS- CLoud Hub to deploy their APIs in cloud.

How and where can I deploy WSO2 APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 has a API Management solution in the cloud. Thats the WSO2 API Cloud which is WSO2 API Manager as a service. You can go to http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/, register and start using the API Cloud. You can find the documentation and tutorial for API Cloud at https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/WSO2+API+Cloud+Documentation

Comment: That is great. So after moving APIs to cloud, will I get an Http endpoint to access the APIs from anywhere in the world?

Comment: Yes you get a http endpoint. If you have your own domain, you can even configure a custom url to your api too.

Comment: Thank you Amila. It worked, is WSO2 Cloud open source?
If Wso2 cloud is not an option since it is not free. What are other ways of hosting my apis on cloud?

Comment: WSO2 Cloud is not for free. You get a trial period of two weeks. After that, you need to upgrade. Subscriptions start at 100 USD per month. I am not aware of any other free service to host your apis. If something is in cloud, there is a cost involved and the vendor has to cover that :). Assume the cost you have to bear if you have to set this up by your own with high availability, alerting, 99.9% uptime etc.